# How can I configure vscode's python debugger to use the project's terminal rather than global?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When using the python debugger with vscode, I would like it to use the terminal that I've selected in my project's `settings.json`, rather than the globally defined terminal.

Specifically, I have WSL's terminal defined as the default terminal used by vscode, and I configure my python projects to use windows cmd with anaconda. When I try to debug python projects using the integrated terminal, it tries to launch the files using WSL, ultimately failing. I want the debugger to use cmd.

I have tried adjusting the `launch.json` in my project, but cannot seem to select an arbitrary terminal in this file.

My `launch.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

which yields these results:

```sh
C:/Users/Owner/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\Owner\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 50893 e:\Software\project\.vscode\launch.json
conda activate base
owner@computer:/mnt/e/Software/project$ C:/Users/Owner/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
-bash: C:/Users/Owner/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate: No such file or directory
owner@computer:/mnt/e/Software/project$ C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\Owner\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 50893 e:\Software\project\.vscode\launch.json
C:UsersOwnerAnaconda3python.exe: command not found
owner@computer:/mnt/e/Software/project$ conda activate base
conda: command not found
owner@computer:/mnt/e/Software/project$
```

If I change the `launch.json` file to use `"console": "internalConsole"`, which allows the software to run, but I am unable to debug anything, breakpoints do not work, etc.

Comment: What does the terminal configuration in settings.json for the project look like?

Comment: My `settings.json` file for the project looks like this:
```{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",

    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",

}```

Comment: I think you might have to kill the existing terminal (using the trash can icon) for this to work, after you open your folder/workspace. The problem is that VSCode itself picks the terminal in which to run that command line. If it doesn't exist, it gets created, and then I'd expect your setting to apply. But if there's a terminal already, then it just tries to execute the command in it - it's not something that the debugger controls.

Comment: I don't see that to be the case - it always tries to run the code using my WSL bash, even when launching a new terminal